# True conditonal statement with false converse

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Is it possible to have a true conditional statement with a false converse? If there is does anyone have an example of one? or why doesn't one exist?

Comment: There are many. E.g., if $n$ is a multiple of $4$, then $n$ is even.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the statement: 
"If it rains, then it is wet."  The converse is false.

For a math statement: 
"If a function is differentiable, then it is continuous."

For a non calculus statement:
"If $4$ divides a number then that number is even." (Brian Scott came up with the same example in the comments)

Answer (score 0):

There is a widely employed distinction between **necessary** ($B \rightarrow A$) and **sufficient** ($A \rightarrow B$) conditions:

> a) If you get an 'A' you will pass the exam. (sufficient, but not necessary)
>
> b) If there's fire then there's oxygen. (necessary, but not sufficient)

You are probably looking for statements where both conditions hold, namely, biconditional statements.